# Instance of 'socket' has no 'gethostbyname' member Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Im coding a chat program with python. But when i write "host = socket.gethostname()" it gives me error. My file is named "server.py" (without quotes) How can i fix? Code:

```py
import socket 

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostbyname()
port = 12347

socket.bind((host, port))

socket.listen(10)

c, addr = socket.accept()

c.sendall(bytes("Hi!".encode("utf-8")))

print("Connected to {}".format(addr))

while True:
    data = str(c.recv(1024))[1:]
    if data:
        print("Client: {}".format(data))
        respond = input("Server: ").encode("utf-8")
        if respond == "q":
            exit()
        else:
            c.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
```

Comment: very bad practice to shadow the module name: `socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`, use another name for your socket variable

Answer (score 2):

this should be a red flag:

```
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

when importing `socket`, `socket` is the socket *module*. The line above assigns the name `socket` to a socket *object*.

Then

```
host = socket.gethostbyname()
```

doesn't work because the method applies to the *module*, but the module name has been reassigned to the socket *object*.

That would work (renaming your socket object):

```
import socket 

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostbyname("localhost")  # needs an argument, btw
```